# Sequence in an array of narrow character type

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The following definition of a *traceable pointer object* is provided in the N3797 standard (sec. 3.7.4.3/1):

> A traceable pointer object is
>
> [...]
>
> — a sequence of elements in an
>   array of narrow character type (3.9.1), where the size and alignment
>   of the sequence match those of some object pointer type.

It isn't simple for me to understand the restriction and I would like to look at the **real example** of such *traceable pointer object*. Could you possibly provide it? I general have a doubt about alignment. As I can see with `alignof`, the alignment of `char` is `1`, but alignment of any pointer to type is `8`...

Comment: I think that describes an array of (`unsigned`)`char`s that hold the value of a trivially copyable type as per [basic.types].

Answer (score 1):

The idea of this section is providing some support for garbage collection (see ): as long as a pointer to an object is kept around it won't be garbage collected. In some contexts it is quite common to store pointers in integers (`intptr_t`) or in byte arrays. Thus, the garbage collector has to consider certain additional representations of pointers beyond pointer types before it can assume that an object is unused.

However, to avoid having the garbage collector search for pointers at arbitrary byte offsets which would cause it to have to do 8 instead of 1 comparison, pointers can't be arbitrarily hidden. Instead, they can be hidden in byte arrays only such that the pointer within the byte array is properly aligned.

Note that the garbage collection support is minimal: it is barely sufficient to allow implementing a garbage collector and give it sane semantics. The C++ standard does not mandate that garbage collection is implemented by an implementation or that objects are automatically garbage collected. However, there exist garbage collection systems for C++.